# PassportJS rename "user" object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am using PassportJS for my login functionalIs there a way to change the "user" object name in the request?

This is how it works now, by default (req.user):

```
function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        req.flash('error', 'Please sign in to access this page.');
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

I would like to use the following instead (req.candidate):

```
function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.candidate) {
        req.flash('error', 'Please sign in to access this page.');
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change it in initialization:

```
 passport.initialize( {
      userProperty: 'student' // defaults to 'user' if omitted
     })
```

This code set: *req.student*

What you will do next depends on you and the used framework.

Look at source code:
[Passport source code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/07bff37406241b0cf8db35986788d2dadbf93763/lib/authenticator.js#L127)